# Remote xDebug not connected to NetBeans, despite the xdebug and ssh-tunnel works?

Tags: netbeans, ssh, xdebug, freebsd

I have a trouble with the connection from remote xDebug to local NetBeans debugger.

**Synopsis:**

**Remote server:** FreeBSD (shared hosting, no root), Apache/Nginx, PHP5.6.
I've installed and configured xdebug with following settings in php.ini:
[debug]

```
zend_extension="/home/USERNAME/usr/php/lib/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9009
;xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/home/USERNAME/logs/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/home/USERNAME/logs/xdebug/profiler/"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/home/USERNAME/logs/xdebug/trace/"
```

USERNAME - is a real user name folder... in other words, the paths are correct, it is tested.
autostart - is just for now, until I will solve a problem.

phpinfo() tells me that xdebug installed successfully.

**Local machine:**

Windows XP, NetBeans, firewalls are off.
I have no a reserved IP, so I've created a reverse SSH-Tunnel via Putty:
`R9009 - localhost:9009`
Remote 9009 port forwards to local 9009, everything seems simple.

Next I went back to remote server and check the tunnel by **netstat -a|grep 9009**

```
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

Ok, next I checked xDebug activity by refreshing my website page in my browser; due to autostart options any request should cause a xdebug data transmittion, and my test shown me that xdebug works well:

```
tcp4       0      0 nosorog.nichost..14107 localhost.9009         SYN_SENT
tcp6       0      0 localhost.9009         *.*                    LISTEN
```

Ok, xDebug tries to establish connection to localhost:9000, but nothing happens on my local machine...

xdebug's log contains the timeout message:
`E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(`

**So, what I've tried:**

First, I decided to re-check if ssh-tunnel works. I just ran simple python script-listener on local machine, and **ssh -p 9009 localhost** on remote server, and connection was successful.

Ok, tunnel works well.

**BUT** neither netbeans nor listener-script receive any connection when xdebug tries to establish connection.

UPD: 
I've tried to establish connection with **telnet** or **nc**, and  that was successfull too...

So at this moment:

- if I try to connect from remote to local via ssh or telnet or netcat - connection is successfull (test script accepts connection, netbeans ignores (if I connect via ssh or telnet) or crashes (if i connect via netcat), but wireshark sees packets in both cases);
- but if xDebug or test script with **sock.connect(('localhost', 9009))** tries to connect - there are SYN_SENT port state and timeout erroron remote machine, and no reaction on local machine (just LISTEN at port 9009 and nothing at all in wireshark)

I guess the clue is **what is the key difference between first and second cases?**

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? What's you xdebug version? Please use only stable versions (2.4.1 is the latest).

Comment: nope, problem is still not solved.  xdebug version is 2.4.1

Comment: From the time I've postet that, I've tried to connect via netcat - the connection weas successfull too, but test script and xdebug session onm remote still ends with timeout error and no reaction on local machine.

Comment: Anything like SELinux or similar on a machine where xdebug/PHP is running (sorry, not a Linux pro person)?

Comment: Also -- *maybe* try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` (in case if IPv6 instead of v4 is used). What xdebug.log has to say? Does it even tries to connect .. or it remains empty?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - have tried, same result.  xdebug.log says `E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(`

Comment: it means - xdebug tries to connect, and as I wrote - I see this try with `netstat -a|grep 9009` on remote server: I see SYN_SENT status, but after second - TIME_WAIT and after some more seconds - connection disappears, inly 'LISTEN' remains

Comment: (apologies in advance for possibly making stupid comments) 1) Originally I thought that SELinux (or alike -- whatever you may have there on FreeBSD) might be blocking outgoing connections e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357399/comments/206959845). Based on the xdebug log and your description -- it is unlikely to be the case. 2) xdebug tries to connect to debug client for only 1 second -- if it does not see proper response -- it continues normal execution.

Comment: 3) On what port NetBeans is listening? is it correct one? I'm PhpStorm user and there you can specify the xdebug port. Can you please check that it's actually NetBeans that listens on local TCP 9009 on Windows machine (e.g. ProcessHacker .. or just netstat or TCPView from sysinternals)

Comment: 4) You see -- in PhpStorm it listens for incoming xdebug connections in 2 cases: a) Debug button pressed so that PHP Debug session is initiated b) "phone handle" icon activated (that just tells IDE to listen on debug ports). In all other cases debug ports are closed (not listening). Since I'm not NetBeans user I cannot tell the exact procedure there -- but maybe it somehow similar?

Comment: 1. AFAIK, SELinux or whatever blocks outgoing connetcions for whole httpd process, right? but in my case curl extension and just  file_get_contents(url) works fine...

Comment: 2. yes, after timeout script continues execution

Comment: 3. 9009 in netbeans, it is correct. futhermore, Ive tried to connect via netcat from remote server (nc localhost 9009) and netbeans on my local machine reacts on this (it just crashes, but i guess it is normal because I send random symbols via netcat), so netbeans listen right port

Comment: 4. I check the fact that NB listens port via netstat on my windows machine too, it does really listen it.

Comment: and more - NB explicity shows when it waits for incoming connection and when not. And as I've said in "3" - it even recieves netcat's connection (but crashes bacause of invalid data)

Comment: ...and I can see via local netstat if NB on local established incoming connection (initiated by netcat on server), but I dont see anything on local machine when xdebug tries to connect

Comment: Out of pure curiosity (to see if it will work at all) -- maybe try PhpStorm: debugging manuals: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm ; IDE itself: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ . I do not have any other ideas, unfortunately. And obviously -- only 1 IDE at a time.

Comment: hmmm... I'll try this of couse, but I really dont think it will help because of there are no incoming connection at all... but... there are strange things happens sometimes :)

Comment: updated question a little (removed out-of-date informations, added som additional from comments)